# Devise login responses with 302 found status

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, response, activeadmin, http-status-code-302

I have implemented a devise setup. Earlier it was working fine, was sending response 200 ok and was redirecting to the mentioned_path.
Now(after cloning into another machine) on login it always responses with 302 found. In the console, it shows 
`Redirected to mentioned_path`

but it keeps processing on the login page.
I can not figure out what is the issue yet.
[image]

```
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
   case resource
    when AdminUser then '/admin/deals#index'
     else super
   end
  end

  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource)
   '/admin'
  end
 end
```

Comment: Show us your custom code please - your sessions controller and where you enforce the redirect.

Comment: ```class ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController 

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    case resource
        when AdminUser then '/admin/deals#index'
        else super
     end
  end

def after_sign_out_path_for(resource)
      '/admin'
   end
  end
```

Comment: when i refresh that processing page(login page after getting response 302 found)
it notices you are already signed in and opens that Mentioned_path

Comment: Did you find the solution @ShaheryarImtiaz?